# Instantiating a function in java like in python

Tags: java, callback

I'm new to Java and trying to figure out how to instantiate a function depending on a specific group ID. I come from a python background, and this is how I could do it in python.

```
if (self.groupid == GROUPID_LUT.one):
    self.group_cb = self._one_cb

elif (self.groupid == GROUPID_LUT.two):
    self.group_cb = self._two_cb

elif (self.groupid == GROUPID_LUT.three):
    self.group_cb = self._three_cb

elif (self.groupid == GROUPID_LUT.four):
    self.group_cb = self._four_cb

else:
    sys.stderr.write("ERROR: Could not obtain group ID.")
    exit(-1)
```

So I could call self.group_cb anywhere and it could call the function I initialized with.

With Java is this possible? Or is this just specific to python?

Thanks.

Comment: Do it the Java way. Create an interface, and implement it with four distinct classes (anonymous classes or lambdas). Instantiate and assign the reference (maybe in your constructor).

Comment: the closest you'll get is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html but java has no real function type

Answer (score 0):

No way to do it exactly the same way, but depending on what you are doing, there are a few ways. Most straight forward is this.

Define interface:

```
public interface I {
    void cb();
}
```

Implement that interface differently for each group ID:

```
public class One implements I {
    @Override public void cb() { ... } // implementation _one_cb
}

public class Two implements I {
   @Override public void cb() { ... } // implementation _two_cb
}

public class Three implements I {
    @Override public void cb() { ... } // implementation _three_cb
}

public class Four implements I {
    @Override public void cb() { ... } // implementation _four_cb
}
```

So you use it:

```
I i;
switch(groupid) {
    case GROUPID_LUT.one:
        i = new One();
        break;
    case GROUPID_LUT.two:
        i = new Two();
        break;
    case GROUPID_LUT.three:
        i = new Three();
        break;
    case GROUPID_LUT.four:
        i = new Four();
}
i.cb();
```

A shorter way to achieve the same is to use anonymous classes (definition of the interface is still needed):

```
I i;
switch(groupid) {
   case GROUPID_LUT.one:
       i = new I() { 
           @Override public void cb() { ... } 
       }; // implementation _one_cb
       break;
   case GROUPID_LUT.two:
       i = new I() { 
           @Override public void cb() { ... } 
       }; // implementation _two_cb
       break;
   case GROUPID_LUT.three:
       i = new I() { 
           @Override public void cb() { ... } 
       }; // implementation _three_cb
       break;
   case GROUPID_LUT.four:
       i = new I() { 
           @Override public void cb() { ... } 
       }; // implementation _four_cb
}
i.cb();
```

Finally the shortest way to achieve the same with Java 8 or above is to use [lambda](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html), but that requires details on what the function is doing.

Comment: Thanks, so my understanding is that you create an interface with a method. You exploit the fact that you can override functions, and you override the interface method with your new callback? 

I guess all the callbacks would have to have the same argument or return the same value If you were to pass in arguments or return a value?

Answer (score 0):

Although Java does not have first-class functions (functions as data) per se, it does have the concept of *functional interfaces*, which, especially in Java 8, behave like functions. The concept of a functional interface is simple. To define one, all you have to do is provide an interface with only one method, like so:

```
public interface MyFunctionalInterface {
    public void process();
}
```

You can optionally place the annotation `@FunctionalInterface` in front of the class; this will cause a compilation error if your class has more than one method. You can then create a subclass of this interface, create a variable of the subclass, and call its one method (thereby 'invoking' the functional interface):

```
public class MyFunctionalClass implements MyFunctionalInterface {
    @Override
    public void process() {
        System.out.println("Processed");
    }
}
```

...Somewhere else...

```
MyFunctionalInterface func = new MyFunctionalClass();
func.process();
```

This simulates first-class functions.
A more common way to do this, with anonymous classes, is:

```
MyFunctionalInterface func = new MyFunctionalInterface() {
    @Override
    public void process() {
        System.out.println("Processed");
    }
};
func.process();
```

And in Java 8, you can shorten this even further, to:

```
MyFunctionalInterface func = () -> { System.out.println("Processed"); };
func.process();
```

With this syntax, put between the `(` and `)` the parameter *names* your function takes. You need not name the types, because the compiler knows them!
Therefore, you can declare an parent interface for `group_cb`, and do this:

```
if (groupid == GROUPID_LUT.one)
    group_cb = _one_cb;

else if (groupid == GROUPID_LUT.two)
    group_cb = _two_cb;

else if (groupid == GROUPID_LUT.three)
    group_cb = _three_cb;

else if (groupid == GROUPID_LUT.four)
    group_cb = _four_cb;

else {
    System.err.println("ERROR: Could not obtain group ID.");
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

**DISCLAIMER: None of this code has been tested or run.**